# Largest and smallest pointer addresses in C

Tags: c, memory-address

Suppose I have the global variables:

```
char *min_ptr, *max_ptr;
```

and the function:

```
void f(int *p)
{
    if(min_ptr > p)
        min_ptr = p;
    if(max_ptr < p)
        max_ptr = p;
}
```

If C does not guarantee that addresses are stored the same way as unsigned long, I guess I can't initialize my variables as follows:

```
char *min_ptr = ULONG_MAX, *max_ptr = 0;
```

How can I initialize min_ptr and max_ptr to the smallest and largest addresses respectively?  And is it even valid to use the <, >, <=, or >= operators with pointers?

Comment: What overall problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: You'd be better off explaining what problem you are trying to solve by comparing pointer values...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?  A function like `bool is_pointer_valid(void *p) { return p >= min_ptr && p < max_ptr; }` is completely useless since it can't handle gaps in the virtual address space or uninitialized values.

Comment: I'm analyzing allocations on the stack.  The only pointers I will be passing to f are those on the stack.

Comment: The stack has gaps, too. (the return addresses and the frame pointers, plus maybe alignment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0` is not a valid address, that's why it's used to represent the null pointer constant. So you can just do:

```
char * min_ptr = NULL;
char * max_ptr = NULL;

/*  Other stuff  */

void f(int *p) {
    if( min_ptr == NULL || min_ptr > p )
        min_ptr = p;
    if( max_ptr == NULL || max_ptr < p )
        max_ptr = p;
}
```

without messing about with that other stuff.

Comment: @user1887231: No, it's not guaranteed to work. Relational operators on pointers have undefined behavior unless both pointers point into the same object, or just past the end of it.

Answer (score 4):

Pointer subtraction or pointer comparison using `<`, `<=`, `>`, or `>=` has *undefined behavior* unless both pointers point to elements of the same array object, or just past the end of it. (For this purpose, a single object is treated as a single-element array.) The relational operators compare the array indices, and subtraction yields the difference in elements (`&arr[5] - &arr[2] == 3`, for example).

It's likely to "work" (i.e., give you more or less consistent results) on most systems, though subtraction may still give nonsensical results if there are alignment problems.

You can convert any pointer-to-object value to `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t` (defined in `<stdint.h>`) and back again without loss of information. Since `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` are integer types, subtractions and comparisons on them are well defined -- but that doesn't mean that the comparison means anything with respect to the pointer values. And of course subtraction can overflow.

You can either live with the fact that your code's behavior is not defined by the standard (though it may happen to work on your system), or you can find a different way to solve your problem. For the latter, we might be able to help if you'll tell us what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

The comparison operators are valid to use.

For the limits, use

```
INTPTR_MIN
INTPTR_MAX
```

from `stdint.h`.

And, FYI, I believe there is a better way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: The relational operators have defined behavior only for pointers into the same object, or just past the end of it.

Comment: I can compare pointers for two different objects. Also, the transitive property always holds.

Comment: You can compare such pointers for equality; the relational operators `<` `<=` `>` `>=` have undefined behavior. See [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) section 6.5.8. It may happen to work, but the behavior is not defined by the C standard.

Answer (score 1):

The header file `<stdint.h>` in C99 has some useful things defined. `uintptr_t` is a normal integer type that can contain a pointer. `stdint.h` defines Maximum and Minimum on all it's types.

So this should work

```
void *ptr_max = UINTPTR_MAX;
```

`UINTPTR_MIN` is not defined as pointer's are unsigned their smallest value is always `0`.

Yes you can compare pointers. It's useful in array stuff. Eg checking a array based ring buffer is not full:

```
// This code has some bugs. Eg, it does not handle wrap arround.
if (ring_buff_back + 1 < ring_buff_front) {...
```

Note the subtraction on pointers return a `ptrdiff_t` which is similar to `intptr_t`.

Comment: `<stdint.h>` defines both `uintptr_t` and `intptr_t`, which are unsigned and signed, respectively. Both are optional. Pointers are neither signed nor unsigned.